# Responsive rotating banner on SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, layout, responsive-design

is there any tool or webPart to add banners to sharepoint 2013 that support responsiveness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need anything SP specific. I've used [flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) in the past for SP and otherwise. Just use REST to populate from your list and call flexslider in the ajax success callback.

(Too long for a comment) I do on my other machine - this is a 2010 example where I used SPServices to do the same thing. Same concept - generate your markup with the response data and apply flexslider after the markup is populated.

```
                $(document).ready(function() {
                  $().SPServices({
                    operation: "GetListItems",
                    async: false,
                    webURL: "/",
                    listName: "Home Slider",
                    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ImageLink' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='SubTitle' />"
                        + "<FieldRef Name='LinkText' /><FieldRef Name='LinkURL' /><FieldRef Name='Description' />"
                        + "</ViewFields>",
                    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                      var myslider;
                      var liHtml = "";
                      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                         liHtml  += "<li style='background:url(" + $(this).attr("ows_ImageLink") + ") no-repeat center top;'>"
                                + "<div class='slideWrap'><div class='slideInnerWrap'>" 
                                + "<h2>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title")        + "</h2>"
                                + "<a href='" + $(this).attr("ows_LinkURL")     + "' class='btn btnOrange btnLarge' >"
                                + $(this).attr("ows_LinkText") + "</a>"
                            + "</div></div>"
                            + "</li>";                                                                                  
                      });
                      $("#sliders").append("<ul class='slides'>" + liHtml + "</ul>");
                      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                        directionNav: true,
                        animation: "slide"
                      });
                    }
                  });
                });
```

Comment: Do you have an example of that? I'm able to use REST to find the list, but to then populate the slider with the elements from the results is what I'm having a problem with. Are you using JSON or Atom?